# Webview crash in safari & wkwebview on iOS12.0.1

Tags: ios, webview, safari, wkwebview

There is an stange crash which only happened on iOS12.0.1, our h5-file is used in the safari and our app's webview. Whenever we open it on iOS12.0.1, it crashed, without any log.

I would like to mention that we do not use "post-message", however, instead of we are using "iframe" to exchange info between app & webview.

Here is the url:
http://avg.163.com/engine/?gameId=747

I need a way to get the webview's crash log. Is there any ways to solve this problem?

THX.

Comment: Now it also happened on iOS 12.1

Comment: Have you checked the web logs while running the device through Safari?

Comment: Yes, but the safari debug mode will be closed when the webview's crash happening.....

Comment: It's too fast ... I can't check any useful info with the safari debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

1. Connect the device to computer (allow trust...)
2. Open Xcode
3. Click Window -> Devices and Simulators
4. Select the device
5. Click View Device Logs

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know this way to get app's crash log, however, this method cannot get the webview crash log.. (I'm not sure that wkwebview's crash will be creating into a .crash file) I can't find any file about the wkwebview's process or safari's on your way.

Comment: Is that webview's crashs are not defined into a true "process crash"?